# Thermochromic, fluorescent fluid

Tags: heat, fluorescence

I'm a total layman in chemistry and am working on an interactive sculpture project and therefore am researching into fluids that have certain properties - long story short:
we are thinking on having a transparent sculpture where a fluid is flowing through it, a fluid that reacts visually on the heat of peoples hands on their touch - so if people touch the sculpture, the fluid changes colour or even emits light in a fluorescent way.
Sorry, I am conscious this may sound super vague and really naive - I'm just trying to reach out to check out possibilities and may come up with interesting insights.
Is there any known way of achieving such an effect? Where could I continue looking after? Any help or pointer towards a certain direction is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not even close?

Answer (score 1):

While thermochromicity already was known for me, for example as thermometer for fish tanks [like here](http://www.hallcrest.com/color-change-basics/liquid-crystal-thermometers), a search based on "thermochromic fluorescent fluid" as keyword yielded this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jDFx7yeBvw).

Beside safety, yet indeed, it is easier to fill the sculptures with a liquid / a solution of a [fluorescent dye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Fluorescent_dyes) excited by black light from the inner of the (glass) sculpture and to wrap the container with thermochromic dyes. These are even commercialized as [here](http://colourchangingink.com/) and [here](https://www.sfxc.co.uk/collections/thermochromatic-thermochromic-pigments-ink-paint).  "Black light" is an other name for ultraviolett light, and there are even hand-size battery powered lamps found in the chemistry lab, or in civil life to check banknotes.

Disclaimer: I have no relationships to the said corporation.

Addendum:  Examples of fluorescence triggered solely by the gentle warmth of a hand are not known to me (yet).

Comment: addition: prolonged exposure to UV may cause eye burn, resulting in severe pain.

Comment: Such fluorescence has nothing to do with touch.

Comment: @permeakra Of course, extended exposure towards UV to skin and eye is harmful ("the dose makes the poison" as Paracelsus said) and I still wonder if the black light deployed in discos was regulated.  On the other hand, if the container were like an amphora and made of glass, the excitation _leading_  to the the fluorescence of the liquid should be done by a light source immersed into the inner of the container.  But as we know, you don't catch a sun burn while sitting on a sunny day behind a window -- because normal glass adsorbs UV-light greatly.

Comment: @MaxW  #1: To quote the OP: "[aiming for an instance where] the fluid changes colour or even emits light in a fluorescent way". From the thermometer at the outer wall of a fish tank, I extrapolate the color changes induced by touching by my hand could happen as well if such dyes were heated as solution, across a sufficiently thin glass wall. #2: And correct, I do not know yet about an example of a dye starting to fluoresce, triggered by warming with a hand worth of 37 Celsius -- were worth a new question, don't you think so, too?

Comment: I'm a chemist. I did XRF as an analytical chemist. I collected fluorescent minerals (UV excitation in dark to see visible light...). Using a UV light is not like shinning a X-ray tube around. // I stand by my NO. There is no such chemical that would behave such as the OP wanted.

Comment: @MaxW - I appreciate your scientific precision and effort of taking me word by word. But I do much more appreciate advise and guidance and a bit of explanations rather than quite simple Yes or No. I reckon this might not be 100% the right platform then, but you know, people are people.

Comment: @alberto2000 - I'm trying to avoid wasting your time looking for something that doesn't exist. I can't imagine any minor tweak to your requirements which would allow such a chemical.